# The metric space $(\mathbb{Q^2},d)$ where $\mathbb{Q^2}= ${ $ (x,y) | x,y \in \mathbb{Q} $ } is a complete metric space when $d$ is

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

The metric space $(\mathbb{Q^2},d)$ where $\mathbb{Q^2}= ${ $ (x,y) | x,y \in \mathbb{Q}  $ } is a complete metric space when $d$ is

> A. The discrete metric
>
> B. The Euclidean metric
>
> C. The taxicab metric

I think none of the above is complete metric space. I think only the constant sequence is convergent in discrete metric space

Can anyone give me hint?

Comment: What are the Cauchy sequences in discrete metric space?

Comment: Fix: The *eventually* constant sequences are convergent, aren't they?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Yes they are. Can you please tell me when $(Q^2,d)$ is complete metric?

Comment: When all Cauchy sequences converge. Now again, what are the Cauchy sequences in discrete metric?